# Inserting Stars in Custom Stargazer table

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

My problem can be understood using the following image

[image]

This is a nice table, except for one problem.  I want the stars (i.e. asterisks) to be superscripts in the log difference column.  How do I do this.

To generate the table I used the following matrix

```
     Log                 Log Difference        
Corn "-4.6242962032095"  "-7.92864907263132***"
HH   "-4.6298901146614"  "-8.72323131664597***"
ICE  "-4.97319261907647" "-7.93380905076848***"
AA   "-4.1611318165187"  "-7.25071259471702***"

res <-structure(c("-4.6242962032095", "-4.6298901146614", "-4.97319261907647", 
"-4.1611318165187", "-7.92864907263132***", "-8.72323131664597***", 
"-7.93380905076848***", "-7.25071259471702***"), .Dim = c(4L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Corn", "HH", "ICE", "AA"), c("Log", 
"Log Difference")))
```

I then pass the `res` matrix to the stargazer function.

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(res, 
          type = "latex",
          title = "Zivot-Andrews Test Statistics", 
          colnames = TRUE, 
          notes = "Sig. Levels: *** p < .01, ** p < .05, * p < .1")
```

The weird thing about this results is that the note correctly specifies the asterisks (i.e. Sig. Levels: *** p<.01,...).

One attempted fix, which did not work, was to specify the matrix entries such as,

```
"-7.92864907263132^{***}"
```

or

```
"$-7.92864907263132^{***}$"
```

Stargazer reads these entries as a string, and not as latex code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code in this package, you're probably better off doing some regex post-processing, e.g.

```
library(stargazer)
startup <- function(x, out=NULL, ...){
  undo <- gsub("\\\\textasteriskcentered", "*", stargazer(x, ...))
  restar <- gsub("* * *", "${}^{***}$", undo, fixed = TRUE)
  restar <- gsub("* *", "${}^{**}$", restar, fixed = TRUE)
  restar <- gsub("* ", "${}^{*}$", restar, fixed = TRUE)
  if(!is.null(out)) cat(restar, file = out, sep="\n")
  restar
}

startup(res, out = "test.tex",
          type = "latex",
          title = "Zivot-Andrews Test Statistics", 
          colnames = TRUE, 
          notes = "Sig. Levels: ${}^{***} p < .01$, ${}^{**} p < .05$, ${}^{*} p < .1$")
```

[image]